# How to align text to left side in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm trying to replicate the design but I'm not really sure how I can make all my text to align to the left just like the design instead of center but not sure how to do it so I will be really appreciated if I can get help or suggestion.

```
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    (widget.tileItems.length < 0)
                        ? null
                        : infoWidget(widget.tileItems[0]),
                    verticalBarSeparator(widget.tileItems[1].middleText),
                    (widget.tileItems.length < 1)
                        ? null
                        : tileWidget(widget.tileItems[1]),
                    verticalBarSeparator(widget.tileItems[2].middleText),
                    (widget.tileItems.length < 2)
                        ? null
                        : tileWidget(widget.tileItems[2]),
                    verticalBarSeparator(widget.tileItems[3].middleText),
                    (widget.tileItems.length < 3)
                        ? null
                        : tileWidget(widget.tileItems[3])
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )



  Widget tileWidget(TileItem item) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 10),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(item.topText, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.h10),
          SizedBox(height: 5),
          Text(item.middleText),
          SizedBox(height: 5),
          Text(item.bottomText,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: int.parse(item.middleText) < 0
                    ? Color.fromRGBO(225, 0, 0, 1)
                    : Color.fromRGBO(67, 188, 72, 1),
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: set the `crossAxisAlignment` of the `Column` widget to `CrossAxisAlignment.left`

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the crossAxisAlignment of the column to left and it should work. Column sets the content to the center if crossAxisAlignment is not changed from the default. Try the following code.

```
 Widget tileWidget(TileItem item) {
return Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 10),
  child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.left,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(item.topText, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.h10),
      SizedBox(height: 5),
      Text(item.middleText),
      SizedBox(height: 5),
      Text(item.bottomText,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: int.parse(item.middleText) < 0
                ? Color.fromRGBO(225, 0, 0, 1)
                : Color.fromRGBO(67, 188, 72, 1),
          ))
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First wrap your verticalBarSeparator and tileWidget inside Row with Alignment start:

```
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    (widget.tileItems.length < 0)
                        ? null
                        : infoWidget(widget.tileItems[0]),
Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    verticalBarSeparator(widget.tileItems[1].middleText),
                    (widget.tileItems.length < 1)
                        ? null
                        : tileWidget(widget.tileItems[1]),
],),
Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    verticalBarSeparator(widget.tileItems[2].middleText),
                    (widget.tileItems.length < 2)
                        ? null
                        : tileWidget(widget.tileItems[2]),
],),
Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    verticalBarSeparator(widget.tileItems[3].middleText),
                    (widget.tileItems.length < 3)
                        ? null
                        : tileWidget(widget.tileItems[3])
],),
                  ],
                ),
```

Second, make your tileWidget Column main and cross alignment like this:

```
Widget tileWidget(TileItem item) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 10),
      child: Column(
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.left,
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
```